# Nav Bar visible only on 4 inch

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I was wondering if the navigation bar can be made visible only if the app is run on a 4 inch display. If it is run on a device with a 3.5 inch display, I would like the nav bar to be invisible/hidden. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use UIScreen to get the screen size and then compare it to the known value for the iPhone 5's screen size. Then, set whether or not the navigation bar should be shown depending on the outcome. Here's an example:

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.0f) {
    // 4 inch screen
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
}else{
    // 3.5 inch screen
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
}
```